# Is there a single common media query for styling all iphone 4, 4s, 5

Tags: iphone, css

Is there a single common media query for styling all iphone in portrait and landscape mode

Comment: You are aware the iPhone 4 has smaller dimensions than the 4s/5

Comment: I am aware of it. I wounder will there a generic approach for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ues following media query :

iPhone in portrait & landscape :

```
  @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

For more information http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ this refrence,its really very helpful.